# global setting in Word to turn off auto-upper-casing feature

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to turn off the auto-capitalization correction at the start of new sentences in Word, and to do it *globally*, rather than on an individual document basis?  I would tell you the version I'm using, if I could find it on the *#*@$$!! ribbon panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [a way](http://word.tips.net/T000480_Turning_Off_Automatic_Capitalization.html):

- Choose AutoCorrect Options from the Tools menu. Word displays the AutoCorrect dialog box.
- Make sure the AutoCorrect tab is displayed:

[image]

- Clear the Capitalize First Letter of Sentences check box.
- Click on OK.

Comment: I don't have a Tools menu. I have `File...Home...Insert...Design...Layout...References...Mailings...Review...View....Tell me what you want to do......Share`